# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Based on the provided shape, [1,1,16,32], the tensor should have 512 values but has 52

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, face-api

I am trying to build a face expression recognition app with [face api](https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/docs/index.html) and [reactjs](https://react.dev/). On locally the app is working fine. but when i deploy to [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) i am getting the below error

[image]

when i  use `serve -s build`  on my local machine, i am getting this error

[image]

This is my code to load the models,

```
  const loadModels = useCallback(() => {
     Promise.all([
      faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri("/models"),
      faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("/models"),
      faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("/models"),
      faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri("/models"),
     ]).then(() => {
    faceDetection();
   });
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    startVideo();
    videoRef && loadModels();
  }, [loadModels]);
```

Got any idea why this is happening?